# MSAL and MultiThreaded Python Flask Web Application compatibility

Tags: azure-active-directory, python-asyncio, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to ascertain if the latest version of MSAL for Python library is compatible with Asyncio library. I've got users who are unable to login with AD authentication and suspect this is a session/threading compatibility issue.

Thanks

Comment: We checked it from our end and there is no compatibility issue documented. Kindly check this link  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication#start-of-content

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and yes, the issue was down to multiple scopes not being given consent.

Answer (score 0):

We checked it from our end and there is no compatibility issue documented. Kindly check this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-authentication#start-of-content)

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and the issue from my end was down to multiple scopes not being given consent